# Not able to create more than 7 partitions on the am335x(beaglebone black) based custom board

Tags: linux, partitioning, fdisk, mmc, beaglebone

I am trying to partition eMMC of BBB(am335x) based custom board,
I am using sfdisk to do that. I am using following command to do that,

```
#Partition emmc 
sfdisk -D -H 255 -S 63 -C 467 /dev/mmcblk0 -uM << EOF
,32,C,*
,200,L
,200,L
,,E
,100,L
,60,L
,200,L
;1269,L
;
EOF
```

But sfdisk shows following partitions and

```
# fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 3841 MB, 3841982464 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 467 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
/dev/mmcblk0p1   *           1           5       40131   c Win95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2               6          31      208845  83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p3              32          57      208845  83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p4              58         467     3293325   5 Extended
/dev/mmcblk0p5              58          70      104391  83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p6              71          78       64228+ 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p7              79         104      208813+ 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p8             105         266     1301233+ 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p9             267         467     1614501  83 Linux
```

but I don't see /dev/mmcblk0p8 and /dev/mmcblk0p9. 
Because of that i am not able to format the /dev/mmcblk0p8.
Can anyone suggest what could be the problem ?

is there a limit on creating extended partitions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Robert C Nelson who replied my query on Beaglebone black community.
One of the configuration, MMC_BLOCK_MINORS [=8] was set to 8 which was preventing driver to create more than 8 device files. I changed number and i am able to see all the partitions and respective device files.

Location:
  │     -> Device Drivers
  │       -> MMC/SD/SDIO card support (MMC [=y])
  │         -> MMC block device driver (MMC_BLOCK [=y])

Hope this helps some having same problem.